# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ItemsService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AppModule context

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I follwed Nest JS Crash tutorial, [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqhNoDE6pb4),
I followed this, but when i import interface in service it shows error

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ItemsService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

I i cloned repository given in tutorial, it is working fine, but when i copy src folder of that repository to my project it then throws error.
here is my Service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Item } from './interfaces/item.interface';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

import { ItemsModule } from './items.module'

import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('Item') private readonly itemModel: Model<Item>) {}
});

}
```

when I comment constructor line it works fine,
I think issue is with this line,

> import { Model } from 'mongoose';

because when i hover on this line it shows could not find declaration for this module.
I even tried copying package.json file of working code to test but still error remains same

> My module Items contains, controller file, service file, module file,
>   dto file, interface file, schema file,

Comment: In you `ItemsModule` are you importing `MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Item', schema: ItemSchema}])`?

Comment: yes i have added this

Comment: Hmm, without seeing you `ItemsModule` and the `ItemSchema` files, it's gonna be hard to debug this. When this happens it is due to the fact that Nest cannot find the Module/Service you are injecting, usually meaning it is either not defined correctly in your Module file, or it is not implemented correctly.

Comment: this helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69646697/using-multiple-modules-in-nestjs

Answer (score 93):

In order to solve it you have to remove the ItemsController and ItemsService imports from the `app.module.ts` file.

This was the solution because:

1. You already import ItemsController and ItemsService in your `items.module.ts` file so it's not necessary to import
   them again in the `app.module.ts` file.
2. In your `items.module.ts` you have the next line:

   ```js
   @Module({
     imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Item', schema: ItemSchema }])],
     ...
   })
   ```

   which is necessary to make the dependency injection in the `items.service.ts` file works, as you can check in the
   `app.module.ts` file you don't have that line.
3. Of course you can add that line to your `app.module.ts` file but then there's no sense to create the
   `items.module.ts` file.

Check my [repo](https://github.com/DanielFryy/NestJS-Crash-Course-TraversyMediaTutorial) xD.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works, however I don't understand why importing ItemsController and ItemsService in the items.module.ts would cause a bug?

Comment: Removing itemsServices and ItemsController from app.module.ts worked.

Comment: Why didn't I think about this solution first -_-

Answer (score 16):

Please remove `ItemsController` and `ItemsService` from `AppModule`. No need include them in `AppModule` because you already import  `ItemsModule` into `AppModule`.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ItemsModule } from "./items/items.module";
import { MongooseModule} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import config from './config/keys';


@Module({
  imports: [ItemsModule, MongooseModule.forRoot(config.mongoURI)],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**items.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Item } from './interfaces/items.interface';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {

    constructor(@InjectModel('Item') private readonly itemModel:Model<Item>){}   

    async findAll(): Promise<Item[]> {
        return await this.itemModel.find();
    }

    async fineOne(id: string): Promise<Item> {
        return await this.itemModel.findOne({_id: id});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I also faced to the same problem.I removed the ItemsController and ItemsService files from the app.module.ts.now it works fine.so the app.module.ts looks like this.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ItemsController } from './items/items.controller';
import { ItemsService } from './items/items.service';
import {MongooseModule} from '@nestjs/mongoose';import { ItemsModule } from 
 './items/items.module';
import config from './config/keys';

@Module({
  imports: [ItemsModule,MongooseModule.forRoot(config.mongoURI)],
  controllers: [AppController ],
  providers: [AppService ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 8):

in app module don't use other controller or provider like as UserController

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/nest'),
    UserModule,
    TasksModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

and others module like user.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'users',
        schema: UserSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
```

Comment: I was missing to export my UserService
'exports: [UserService]'

Answer (score 6):

If you have two modules depends on each others
don't import them directly use forwardRef() in both modules

Source [Circular dependency](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

```
@Module({
  imports: [
     MongooseModule.forFeature([
       { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema },
     ]),
    forwardRef(() => BusinessModule),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
  exports: [MongooseModule],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

and in the other module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
       { name: 'Business', schema: BusinessSchema },
     ]),
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
  ],
  providers: [BusinessService, BusinessResolver],
  exports: [MongooseModule],
})
export class BusinessModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it in this way-

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'nest-react-auth',
      entities: [User],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Here I've added my entity file **User** - `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),` and solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I added this in item module and solved

```
imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Item])],
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem. For me I missed the ServiceClass in providers field in one of the submodule. Then I specified it like below and error gone.

```
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'test', schema: testSchema }])],
  controllers: [TestController],
  providers: [TestService],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

please import @ItemModule in your other module where you want to use it.
https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32265165)

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem, then I remove itemService and itemController line from the controller and provider and the error is solved.