# Nestjs Error: Cannot find module './app.controller'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, controller, nestjs

I cant seem to locate where the error is coming from as the app compiled with `Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.` I have seen similar resolve on StackOverflow but none seem to address the issue

Here is the stack trace

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './app.controller'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\DELL\Documents\DokunFiles\Nestjs\app\api\dist\src\app.module.js
- C:\Users\DELL\Documents\DokunFiles\Nestjs\app\api\dist\src\main.js
```

With the appModule below, the app controller is properly imported into the app module

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';


@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_URI,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    , UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's weird, I'm encountering the same error. Glad i'm not the only one. I noticed the controller is not compiled in the dist/src folder.

Comment: I had the same issue. running `prebuild` solved it for me as well. Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Run:

```
npm run prebuild
```

or

```
rimraf dist
```

or

```
 rm -rf dist/
```

And try again.

---

I had the same issue:

```
stanislas@yeji > nest start                                                                                                    api -> master ! ? RC=130
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './app.controller'
Require stack:
- /Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api/dist/src/app.module.js
- /Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api/dist/src/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api/dist/src/app.module.js:13:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api/dist/src/app.module.js',
    '/Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api/dist/src/main.js'
  ]
}
```

And noticed the controller was indeed not compiled:

```
stanislas@yeji > ll dist/src/                                                                      api -> master ! ?
total 48
-rw-r--r--  1 stanislas  staff   138B Apr 19 17:45 app.module.d.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 stanislas  staff   2.1K Apr 19 17:45 app.module.js
-rw-r--r--  1 stanislas  staff   753B Apr 19 17:45 app.module.js.map
-rw-r--r--  1 stanislas  staff    11B Apr 19 17:45 main.d.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 stanislas  staff   340B Apr 19 17:45 main.js
-rw-r--r--  1 stanislas  staff   290B Apr 19 17:45 main.js.map
drwxr-xr-x  5 stanislas  staff   160B Apr 19 17:52 migration
```

But I noticed it worked as `prod`:

```
stanislas@yeji > npm run build && npm run start:prod                                                                             api -> master ! ? RC=1

> soundbase-api@0.0.1 prebuild /Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api
> rimraf dist


> soundbase-api@0.0.1 build /Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api
> nest build


> soundbase-api@0.0.1 start:prod /Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api
> node dist/main

[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +34ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +56ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {}: +3ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/login, POST} route +3ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/profile, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RoutesResolver] UserController {/users}: +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, PUT} route +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 95175   - 04/19/2020, 6:40:45 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
```

And then it automagically started working again:

```
stanislas@yeji > npm start                                                                                                     api -> master ! ? RC=130

> soundbase-api@0.0.1 start /Users/stanislas/git/soundbase/api
> nest start

[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:00 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:00 PM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +35ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:00 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:00 PM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:00 PM   [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:00 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +56ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {}: +3ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/login, POST} route +2ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/profile, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RoutesResolver] UserController {/users}: +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 95255   - 04/19/2020, 6:41:01 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
```

Since I already tried `nest build && node dist/main.js` beforehand, I'm pretty sure `npm run prebuild` aka `rimraf dist` (which just `rm -rf dist/`) did the trick. Since the issue was in the `dist` folder, that seems logical enough for me. Not sure what the exact issue was though.

Comment: I did what you suggested so I got ```Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the UserModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If UserModel is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If UserModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserModel */ ]
  })```

Comment: It's working now. After running the command, I got the above error the I reference this link on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870498/nest-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-itemsservice-please-make-sure-that-t. Thanks man

Answer (score 7):

Look for `"incremental": true` in your `tsconfig.json` file. The true makes incremental updates. Setting it to false hopefully will save you having to clean `dist` every time

Comment: So incremental would save just time locally developing the app since it would compile faster? Btw. this worked for a similar bug in my nestjs application :D

Answer (score 1):

Check file extension. In my case file with controller has .js extension, but must .ts

Answer (score 1):

After creation of custom lib from the official documentation

```
nest g library my-library
```

AND even running

```
npm run prebuild
```

I was always getting the same error because of the files ("libs" dir) outside of src that were being compiled.

[image]

Here was my dist folder:

[image]

I solved with adding "libs" for excluded files in tsconfig.build.ts

[image]